# Is there any way to set a control at the center of the window with one button in some Visual options?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

My question is not about keeping controls in center after a resize of the window. Only thing I want to know is am I able to center controls like on the image below with some Visual Studio option and not doing it by hand?[image]

Comment: Using a TableLayoutPanel or a FlowLayoutPanel, yes you can. But if you are looking for a VS menu/toolbar command for arranging controls like this, no there's not such a command.

Comment: Just in case, select them and from VS menu select `Format` -> `Center in Form` -> `Horizontally`. You can find these commands (add them if not already there) on the ToolBar by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set controls at the center of the window, you can refer to the following steps:

First create a TableLayoutPanel and Edit Rows and Columns.

[image]

Second you can edit the row and column style in this interface.

[image]

Then you can add you Buttons into the TableLayoutPanel like this

[image]

Finally just select the TableLayoutPanel and click Format on the menu and choose Horizontally under Center in Form. The controls will be set at the center of the window.

[image]